# have troubles downloading the freebase dump file

Tags: download, dump, freebase

I am trying to download the dump file (the 22GB zip file) from "https://developers.google.com/freebase/data".
It seems like the download link is not available.
Is it going to be available soon?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.
The link is broken, but the list of available dumps is available on the following page:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public

It is possible to download the dumps using the following link:
//commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public/rdf/

For example, the latest release at the time of this post is 'freebase-rdf-2014-11-23-00-00.gz' which can be downloaded using the following link:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public/rdf/freebase-rdf-2014-11-23-00-00.gz